# cannot include file within included file to use API functions/objects

Tags: php, include, php-include, php-carbon

so I am using the carbon api in the mylibfunctions.php, but also of course on the page itself. PHP won't let you include a file twice, so how do I go about including/referencing the file in mylibfunctions.php?

```
index.php:

 <?php
include('session-info.php');
include('phpsqlinfo_dbinfo.php');
include('carbon.php');
use Carbon\Carbon;
include('mylibfunctions.php'); //using carbon functions here
```

not including the carbon API files on the mylibfuncitons returns this error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Carbon' not found in /var/www/mylibfunctions.php on line 4
```

and including them returns something like:

```
cannot require blah blah blah more than once. (not exact error message).
```

sincere thanks for any help. It is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Use `include_once` function instead.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php

Comment: should I include the api files in both files(using include_once)?

Comment: doesn't seem to work when i do that, although not getting any error.

Comment: the included functions run perfectly when copied an pasted on the initial page.

Comment: If you are using the API in both files, I'd say you should include_once in both files (it does not hurt anyway).
So, what is it that does not work? Carbon API functions? The functions in 'mylibfunctions.php`?